# Ruby gem install SocketError

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Since 1 hour, i've an error on my console when i want install new gem (Windows and Linux) :

```
WARNING:  Error fetching data: SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

My ruby version : 1.9.3 (linux) and 2.1 (windows)
Gem version : 1.8.23

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

RubyGems.org's DNS provider is [currently having an outage](https://twitter.com/rubygems_status/status/539500893108854785). If you need immediate access, [they say](https://twitter.com/rubygems_status/status/539513292105187328):

> @rubygems_status: Status update: If you need immediate access, you can try 54.186.104.15. Please remember this may change in the future.

Comment: Currently, I have this message :( i can't install gems

Comment: I've this message : Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)